# SignalrR transport from WASM

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, .net-7.0, hosted-blazor-webassembly

I have a hosted .net 7 Blazor WASM project, that uses a SignalR connection with the host. The communication is established, and it works. So far so good. What I have noticed, is that although a WebSocket connection is established, the communication is still using *long-poll + calls*. Not even SSE. This is the dev environment, with both the client and the server running on the same machine - so nothing is blocking WS. One detail: the [AccessTokenProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=dotnet#configure-bearer-authentication) is set for the connection options.

Why is this? Is this somehow related to the dev env or WASM? Or is this what I should expect for the prod as well?

*[Update 23-12-27]*
Following @JasonPan's advice, I added client side logging. The result:
[image]
(btw: browser is Edge... not supporting SSE???)
Error expanded:
[image]

Server side log:

[image]

From what I see, the connection is not refused, only challenged .
And the actual WS connection has the token requested.

[image]

This is the client code:

[image]

And server:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want to fix the issue, it's better to provide a sample which could reproduce the issue, and hide your sensitive information. I will help you to investigate it.

Answer (score 0):

I have test it and haven't facing this issue. So please kindly check via steps below.

**1. Check you Server side setting, if there any longpolling settings like below**

```
 app.MapHub<YourHub>("/yourHub", options =>
 {
     options.Transports = HttpTransportType.LongPolling;
 });
```

**2. Check your client side settings, if has some code like below**

```
hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("https://localhost:7262/mainHub?uid=jason_WASM&sid=test&api-key=112233", options =>
    {
        options.Transports = HttpTransportType.LongPolling;
    })
    .Build();
```

**3. Check where your SignalR Server is deployed?**

If you deploy IIS on Windows 10/11, the default number of websocket connections is 10, so you may experience an over-the-limit connection.

**My Test Result**

*SignalR.razor*

```
@page "/signalr"

<PageTitle>SignalR</PageTitle>

@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client
@implements IDisposable

<div>
    <input type="text" @bind="userToSend" placeholder="User Name" />
    <input type="text" @bind="messageToSend" placeholder="Message" />
    <button @onclick="SendMessage">Send Message</button>
</div>

@if (messages != null)
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var message in messages)
        {
            <li>@message</li>
        }
    </ul>
}

@code {
    private HubConnection hubConnection;
    private List<string> messages = new List<string>();
    private string userToSend;
    private string messageToSend;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("https://localhost:44310/mainHub?uid=jason_WASM&sid=test&api-key=112233", options =>
            {
                // Configure options here if needed
            }).ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
                logging.AddProvider(new BrowserConsoleLoggerProvider(JSRuntime));
            })
            .Build();

        hubConnection.On<string, string>("Chat_ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
        {
            var formattedMessage = $"{user}: {message}";
            messages.Add(formattedMessage);
            StateHasChanged();
        });

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }

    private async Task SendMessage()
    {
        if (hubConnection != null && hubConnection.State == HubConnectionState.Connected)
        {
            await hubConnection.SendAsync("Chat_SendMessageToAll", userToSend, messageToSend);
        }
    }

    public bool IsConnected => hubConnection?.State == HubConnectionState.Connected;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _ = hubConnection?.DisposeAsync();
    }
}
```

*BrowserConsoleLogger.cs*

```
using Microsoft.JSInterop;

namespace BlazorWASM
{
    public class BrowserConsoleLogger : ILogger
    {
        private readonly string _categoryName;
        private readonly IJSRuntime _jsRuntime;

        public BrowserConsoleLogger(string categoryName, IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
        {
            _categoryName = categoryName;
            _jsRuntime = jsRuntime;
        }

        public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state) => null;

        public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel) => true;

        public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
        {
            var message = $"{logLevel}: {_categoryName}[{eventId.Id}] {formatter(state, exception)}";
            _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", message);
        }
    }
}
```

*BrowserConsoleLoggerProvider.cs*

```
using Microsoft.JSInterop;

namespace BlazorWASM
{
    public class BrowserConsoleLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
    {
        private readonly IJSRuntime _jsRuntime;

        public BrowserConsoleLoggerProvider(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
        {
            _jsRuntime = jsRuntime;
        }

        public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
        {
            return new BrowserConsoleLogger(categoryName, _jsRuntime);
        }

        public void Dispose() { }
    }
}
```

Then you can check which protocol used in browser develop tools Concole windows.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will check with logging tomorrow, but I am sure that there is no explicit transport set. The server is a self-hosted app for now, but it will be a Windows server with IIS 11 or 10  in production. Anyway, in dev there is only a single connection to that hub, so no limit should apply.

Comment: Please see update in question

Comment: After investigating the error message, more precisely the query that it is associated with, I noticed the access_token being passed. Then I found this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-7.0#built-in-jwt-authentication . I missed that event handler. It was confusing, but the note on the link makes it clear:

Comment: Hi @ZorgoZ Is this possible to solve this problem if deployed on a server? As far as I know, the operating system for personal use, there is a link limit of 10 websockets.

Comment: This had nothing to do with the OS. Only "Home" has some limitations, "Pro" has not. Anyway, It had a single connection. Again: the issue was how the auth token is passed around when upgrading the connection to websocket. Actually how it is not passed around. But the solution is on the Microsoft page linked by me in the previous comment.